# Spring AOP transaction annotation not working on method invoked using java reflection

Tags: reflection, aspectj, spring-aop, spring-transactions

I have a method in my `@Transaction` enabled class which is getting invoked from outside class using java reflection. Unfortunately Spring Transaction is not working inside this method.
Class looks something like below:

```
@Transactional
public class CartServiceImpl implements CartService {

@Autowired
AnnotatedMethodInvoker annotatedMethodInvoker;

@Override
@VersionedParent
public BasicResponse addCartItem(AddCartItemRequest addCartItemRequest) throws Exception{
    String currentMethodName = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName();
    return (BasicResponse)annotatedMethodInvoker.invoke(this, currentMethodName, addCartItemRequest, AddCartItemRequest.class);
}

@VersionedMethod(parentMethod="addCartItem", minimumVersion=Constants.BUILD_VERSION_1_0_1, description="Added Epoch")
private BasicResponse addCartItemWithEpoch(AddCartItemRequest addCartItemRequest){
      /***** Implementation detail goes here *****/
}

@VersionedMethod(parentMethod="addCartItem", minimumVersion=Constants.BUILD_VERSION_1_0_2, description="Added Cart filter here")
private BasicResponse addCartItemWithCartFilter(AddCartItemRequest addCartItemRequest){
      /***** Implementation detail goes here *****/
}
```

}

In the `AnnotatedMethodInvoker` class's `invoke()` method I am invoking 1 of the two `private` methods  `addCartItemWithEpoch()` &  `addCartItemWithCartFilter()`.

The problem is that when a RuntimeException is occurring, the Transaction is still getting committed, which essentially means that Spring Transaction is not working in my private method.
Surprizingly the below statement returns true if I put it inside my private method:

```
TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()
```

My application is currently using Spring AOP transaction throughout and it works seamlessly. application-config.xml snippet below:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.apraxalpha.dealernews" />
<tx:annotation-driven />
```

I have read this [blog](http://blog.timmlinder.com/2011/01/spring-transactional-checking-for-transaction-support-and-local-method-calls/) which suggests using AspectJ based Transaction over Spring AOP Transaction approach. I am not really confident about this, because my entire application is otherwise using Spring AOP based Transaction. now just for 1 single implementation change, I don't want to change everything to AspectJ transaction. 
1) Is there any such middle path to have both the approaches in my application ?
2) Is there any other way to have Transaction in my private method getting invoked using java reflection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Went through several other posts on similar problem : 
1) Spring Transaction not working while calling private method of a Spring Bean class or 
2) calling a method from another method in same class

Seems like either you use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP to call the bean class methods
OR
If you don't want to use AspectJ and stick to Spring AOP then a simple refatoring of the class will solve the problem as below:

In the question the method public method addCartItem and the actual implementation methods(which are actually having the implementation code) are all in the same bean class.
Consider creating a delegator class as a layer above this bean class and put the public method addCartItem in that class. Then make the both private methods as public and try to call the bean class methods from the delegator method.